# Next Capital letter using Regex Search

Tags: regex, editplus

I use EditPlus.

This tool has a nice search option where you can search either regular text or RegEx search.

I want to search for the next Uppercase alphabet preceeded by a lowercase alphabet. What do I put in the search box for this?

Comment: What alphabet are you using? Could there be letters in your text that are not in the English alphabet?

Comment: @Mark Byers This is an ASCII text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[A-Z][a-z]+` should do it.

*Translation: Exactly one capital letter, followed by one or more lowercase letters.*

**Edit:** I had the relationship backwards:

`[a-z]+[A-Z]+`

*Translation: One or more lower-case letters, followed by one or more upper-case letters.*

Answer (score 2):

`[a-z][A-Z]` should match a lowercase character followed immediately by an uppercase character